# how to run jmeter test in non gui mode when i have planned the test on gui

Tags: jmeter

I have planned a test on Jmeter in GUI mode which I want to run on the linux based server. And the Jmeter on the server is in non-GUI mode, so how do i alter the jmx of my test plan so that it start executing on non-GUI mode? I tried executing it like I did on cmd of the PC where I built the test i.e "JMeter -n -t Text.jmx". But it is not executing as the test plan is made in the GUI mode.
Basically problem in jmx is this:
"HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="crw" enabled="true""
So how do I replace this to run in non-GUI mode.
Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to change to switch from gui to non-gui mode.

what is your error ?

This command line should work:

```
 <JMETER_HOME>/bin/jmeter -t <Path to Test Plan> -n -l <path to results>/results.csv
```

Comment: these are the errors
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate commons-net in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate geronimo-activation-1.1-spec in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate geronimo-javamail-1.4-provider in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate jboss-j2ee in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate junit in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: No JAVA_CMD set for run_java, falling back to JAVA_CMD = java

Comment: how are you launching jmeter exactly ? show the folder structure and the exact command line. Also rub java -version and show output.Finally which jmeter version are you running ?

Comment: apache-jmeter-2.11. I copied the jmx file from my pc to server pc and changed the path of the files as required. and used this commad to execute the jmeter test: JMeter -n -t Test.jmx.

Comment: please answer all questions

Comment: please do pwd and show output in jmeter folder. Do also java -version and show outout. In bin folder run ./jmeter.sh -n -t testname.jmx

Comment: could you put all informations in initial question ? still missing info to help, If Answer helped you solve issue then you should accept it

Comment: I figured out the problem. The version of jmeter in the server was different, so it was not even executing. Thanks for your concern :)